# Django: sorl-thumbnail

Tags: django, sorl-thumbnail

This is my code

```
{% thumbnail  ham.thumbnail_url "50x20" crop="center" as im %}
   <img src="{{ im.url }}" width="{{ im.width }}" height="{{ im.height }}">
{% endthumbnail %}
```

and this is what the img src output looks like

```
cache/81/a8/81a884b2bce95dfe60e7397ea15d10f2.jpg
```

even with this example from the [docs](http://readthedocs.org/docs/sorl-thumbnails/en/latest/examples.html#model-examples)

```
 {% thumbnail "http://www.aino.se/media/i/logo.png" "40x40" crop="80% top" as im %}
 <img src="{{ im.url }}">
 {% endthumbnail %}
```

What's wrong?

**Update**:

```
{% thumbnail  ham.thumbnail_url "220x120" crop="center" as foo %}
<img src="{{MEDIA_ROOT}}{{ foo.url }}" width="{{ foo.width }}" height="{{ foo.height }}">
{% endthumbnail %}
```

Now i have a directory called 'cache' inside the 'media' directory that contains all the images, and the generated code is

```
 <img width="220" height="120" src="/media/cache/c6/5d/c65d3cd46c4ef6154c788526bfa3447f.jpg">
```

and this is my settings

```
 MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'media')
 MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
 STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

but i can't see the images on screen == failed to load a given url(firebug)

One possible way to make it work is to auto generate the cache directory inside the static directory. Works for me if i copied the cache dir to static dir and changed the settings to

```
MEDIA_URL = ''
<img src="{{STATIC_URL}}{{ foo.url }}" width="{{ foo.width }}" height="{{ foo.height }}">
```

Comment: i can't see anything wrong with that url.

Comment: Yes, may be I miss something or a library!

Comment: @Ahmed, what's wrong? Is the image file corrupted? Is it not the image you're looking for? Is it not the correct size? The file name looks correct, if that's what you're concerned about.

Comment: @Yuji, I think every thing you mention is ok, but still not working

Comment: Are you having problems with the development server, or production server?  Try changing to <img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{im.url}}" >  . From the docs, what you have looks right, but I think the URL should be preceded by the MEDIA_URL.

Comment: @mtnpaul Still not working, i think because i get the image from Api.

Comment: I'm going to downvote now - please be more precise when asking questions in the future.

Comment: @ahmed, the point of my question is that we have no idea what your problem is. Is it that the image won't display? Is the url returning a 404? "It's not working" does not describe the problem. There are people who'd like to help you here!

Comment: I'm so sorry, I get cache/81/a8/81a884b2bce95dfe60e7397ea15d10f2.jpg, I have a directory called 'cache' that contains all the images. As @c4urself said, I changed the  STATIC_URL settings and it works after i moved the 'cache' directory to the static directory. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the standard way for sorl-thumbnail to name its files. The files are resized by whatever arguments you call thumbnail tag with. The result is a url which looks like cache/81/a8/81a884b2bce95dfe60e7397ea15d10f2.jpg. If you're not seeing anything you may want to look at your STATIC_URL settings.

Many sites have a static url, such that your image src will show up as

http://static.example.com/cache/81/a8/81a884b2bce95dfe60e7397ea15d10f2.jpg

or

http://example.com/media/cache/81/a8/81a884b2bce95dfe60e7397ea15d10f2.jpg

Comment: I have a folder called cache that includes all the images, still confused on how to link to it. how to get this part static.example.com/ Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change your media root:  `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'media')`

To something like this on LOCAL:

`MEDIA_ROOT = /home/user/project/app/media/`

`MEDIA_URL = /site_media/`

For production I did something like this:

`MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/user/webapps/media/'`

`MEDIA_URL = 'http://domain.com/site_media/'`

I have had a problem with this when I switched to the new sorl, but everything works for me now. Hope this helps.